# How to fill values of a (2,3,4) array using a (2,3) array of indices and a (2,3) array of new values

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following arrays.

```
b0 = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])

b1 = np.array([
    [1, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 1]
])

b2 = np.array([
    [100, 0, 0],
    [200, 300, 0]
])
```

My goal is to update values of `b0` using indices specified in `b1` and new values given by `b2`. Specifically, I want to make these updates

```
b0[0, 0, b1[0,0]] = b2[0,0]
b0[0, 1, b1[0,1]] = b2[0,1]
b0[0, 2, b1[0,2]] = b2[0,2]

b0[1, 0, b1[1,0]] = b2[1,0]
b0[1, 1, b1[1,1]] = b2[1,1]
b0[1, 2, b1[1,2]] = b2[1,2]

b0
array([[[  0, 100,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],
       [[200,   0,   0,   0],
        [300,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

How do I do this dynamically?

Comment: `for t in np.ndindex(b2.shape): b0[(*t,b1[t])]=b2[t]` but I won't post it as an answer because it involves a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [51]: b1 = np.array([
    ...:     [1, 0, 2],
    ...:     [0, 0, 1]
    ...: ])
    ...: 
    ...: b2 = np.array([
    ...:     [100, 0, 0],
    ...:     [200, 300, 0]
    ...: ])
In [52]: b0 = np.zeros((2,3,4),int)
In [53]: b0[np.arange(2)[:,None], np.arange(3), b1] = b2
In [54]: b0
Out[54]: 
array([[[  0, 100,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[200,   0,   0,   0],
        [300,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

`np.arange(2)[:,None], np.arange(3)` broadcast together to index a (2,3) block, same as `b1` shape.

`meshgrid` lets us compare my indexing and yours:

```
In [58]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2), np.arange(3), sparse=True, indexing='ij')
Out[58]: 
[array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2]])]
In [59]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2), np.arange(3), sparse=False, indexing='ij')
Out[59]: 
[array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realized I can do this

```
n = b0.shape[0]
k = b2.shape[1]
i1 = np.repeat(np.arange(n), k)
i2 = np.tile(np.arange(k), n)
b0[i1, i2, b1[i1, i2]] = b2[i1, i2]
```

but there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: With broadcasting `i1` and `i2` can be (2,1) and (3,) shaped.  (compare `np.meshgrid` with and without `sparse` parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
ind = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(b1))
ind1, ind2 = zip(*ind)

b0[ind1, ind2, b1[ind1,ind2]]=np.ravel(b2)
```

However I see it's `0` on `(0,0,0)`, while you have `200` there - which I feel might be your overlook (correct me, if I'm wrong though)...